# Sklearn: Multiclass Problem with Model for each class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following problem:

I want to make a binary classification (yes/no) for a given dataset. This dataset contains X classes. Now I want to create a model for each class and predict yes/no for each class. Afterwards I want to return the top n classes sorted by probability (I will solve this with the proba-method). The reason I want to create a model for each class is, that the amount of classes is very big and for some classes a single model for their own might be better.

- I want to create a separate model for each class and feed it only with its own data
- The class itself is not an argument to pass for the ml model, it is just needed for the initialisation of models
- I want to perform hyperparameter tuning for each submodel separately, because each class could have their own properties

Do you know of any viable solution for sklearn? OneVsOne or Multioutput seem to be viable solutions, but from my understanding both of them consume all datapoints not separated by class.
Do I need to create my own solution?

Comment: Have you considered trying [`sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it seems like the same problem. I can split the model, but not the data, so each model receives each others data. Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: No, I think I misunderstood.  Although I don't really know what _"... and feed it only with its own data"_ means.

Comment: Basically I mean that I have a dataset with several values. One column inside this dataset is the Class A,B,C,D. Now with the given data I want to create a binary model for each class, because the final result should be a prediction of the individual outcome of each class. (A yes, B no, C no, D yes). And now comes the point with the data: I only want to train Model A with data from class A, Model B with data from class B and so on. But from my understanding I always feed each model with the data from all classes, which makes no sense in my use case.

Comment: Without data from other classes how you would discriminate? If your class A model see points with label A only, it'll not know what is "not A".

Comment: Actually I want to use the data for live predictions. But outside of the training dataset I will not know the class. Therefore I want to make a proba prediction for each class and recommend all classes bypassing a certain threshold. The problem is there are a lot of classes which might not be good for every model, so I wanted to split them up.